# How can i add click listener to google map road?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm a beginner with the Google Maps API, and wrote this JavaScript code to show a simple road map to the end user:

```
var originLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(OrginLat, OrginLng);
        var destinationLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(DestLat, DestLng);

            directionsService.route({
                origin: originLatLng,
                destination: destinationLatLng,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                } else {
                    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                }
            });



        }//end of function
```

Now I want to enable click events on the road. For example when a user clicks on the road, show an alert. How can I write that code? Thanks all.

Comment: i did not know that answer was given..next tym i will be more alert while giving answers

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(){
    if(map.mapTypeId == "roadmap"){
        alert('ok')
    }
})
```

Comment: Ok,your code run when click on the map,but i want when click on the road show ok

Comment: i dont know whether its possible or not...sry i have not tried that but if i find anything similar to your problem i will post it